# VS Code C# extension reporting missing .NETFramework,Version v4.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, target-framework

my intention is to run a C# project I downloaded from GitHub in VS Code (Win10) since I have no option to install Visual Studio. I'm doing this for the first time and I have no C# experience.

First, I installed the C# (OmniSharp) extension.
Second, I opened the project folder.

As soon as I do that the C# extension tries to start the OmniSharp server.
A couple of seconds later I receive the error message: 
[image]

The log shows:

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
>           The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

I had already installed .NET Core 2.1 SDK (v2.1.300) & .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack.

Running `dotnet --info` shows:

> .NET Core SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
>    Version:   2.1.300
>    Commit:    adab45bf0c
>
> Laufzeitumgebung:
>    OS Name:     Windows
>    OS Version:  10.0.16299
>    OS Platform: Windows
>    RID:         win10-x64
>    Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\
>
> Host (useful for support):
>     Version: 2.1.0
>     Commit:  caa7b7e2ba
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>     Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Registry shows the following:
[image]

Next this I tried is change the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` value in the .csproj file to v4.7.2 but to no avail.

I can't figure out what's wrong.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: VSCode can only handle .NETCore projects.  This isn't, you need VS.

Comment: Oh wow, that didn't reveal itself to me. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack does not replace others. You still need to install them manually from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks